# How to save the passwords in Template?

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, apache-nifi

I have created template for perform data movement to SQL Server.

My problem is `'I need to share the template to 100 members who have access to use'.`

If i share the template ,it doesn't have sensitive values in DBCPConnectionPool.

Is there is any way to save the sensitive values in Template Itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Templates intentionally do not include any values marked as sensitive by the processor/component. The risk for accidental exposure of sensitive values was determined to be too high.

I have filed [NIFI-3110](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-3110) to enable templates to export variable registry references for sensitive property values. Once this is implemented, if you wish to share these, you can reference the [Variable Registry](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#custom_properties) and include that definition file with the template when you share between users.

Comment: half a decade later, this is still marked as to-do. alternatives?